# Can't see "network" in finder (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, finder, osx-mountain-lion

Can't see the "network" in finder at all. My girlfriend's MBP and old Windows laptop successfully sees all the files, shared from Ubuntu file server, but not my new MBP. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the "answer" but reinstalled Mountain Lion from scratch and simply got the "Shared" (not "Network") section with my Ubuntu comp. Still can't get why, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MBP is in the same Windows workgroup as your Ubuntu server and her MBP.

System Preferences > Network > [interface] > Advanced > WINS

Comment: she never typed in any workgroup name... it always just was there, I'll check later anyways